# I have got an error in my source code, I have tried to create a JDBC connection, but ClassNotFoundException occures. What shoud i do now?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, oracle10g, netbeans-8

```
import java.sql.*;
class MySQLconn
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","12345");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from emp");
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("id")+" "+rs.getString("Name")+" "+rs.getString("Department"));
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        con.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Full error log please

Comment: Did you add the Oracle Database JDBC driver JAR file to the classpath?

Comment: run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.class.getName()

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the Oracle JAR's are not in your classpath. A trick to make sure they are at compile time is to import the OracleDriver class and then replace the string literal with OracleDriver.class.getName(). Your IDE or the compiler will notice if the class is not available.

Obviously, you need to get the Oracle JAR's and put them on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

from your exception It seems you dont have Oracle Database Driver in your project classpath, you can download one in here [oracle jdbc driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)

If you using ecelipse IDE you can add the driver by following these steps :

1. Right click on your project folder
2. Choose build path > configure build path
3. switch to Libraries tab, then choose Add External Jars